# Docker Run bash after wildfly/JBoss startup

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, jboss, wildfly

I have a Dockerfile:

```
## SELECT IMAGE
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt install -y openjdk-11-jdk && \
    apt install -y wget

## SET JAVA ENV
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64

## COPY CONF FILES TO ROOT
COPY conf/root/ssh/authorized_keys /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
COPY conf/root/subversion/auth /root/.subversion/auth

## INSTALL JBOSS
RUN wget -O /tmp/wildfly-16.0.0.Final.tar.gz \
    https://download.jboss.org/wildfly/16.0.0.Final/wildfly-16.0.0.Final.tar.gz && \
    tar zxvf /tmp/wildfly-16.0.0.Final.tar.gz -C /opt

## JBOSS CONFIG
RUN sed -i -r 's/jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1/jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0/' \
    /opt/wildfly-16.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml

## CLEAN JOSS
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

EXPOSE 8080 9990


CMD /opt/wildfly-16.0.0.Final/bin/add-user.sh --silent=true admin admin
CMD /opt/wildfly-16.0.0.Final/bin/standalone.sh -b=0.0.0.0
CMD /bin/bash
```

I want to start wildfly and after it is started I want to have a bash of this container.
The problem is that I will never get to the point where `CMD /bin/bash` is called because `CMD /opt/wildfly-16.0.0.Final/bin/standalone.sh -b=0.0.0.0` is blocking the container with this message:

```
INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990/management
INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 16.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 8.0.0.Final) started in 2526ms - Started 305 of 531 services (324 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

I tried to do it the way I wrote above but also remove the `CMD /bin/bash` line from the Dockerfile and create another Dockerfile which should give me a shell and run those two Dockerfiles with a docker-compose but everytime the wildfly status is blocking my further actions.

Answer (score 0):

You should only have one CMD in your Dockerfile and it should be the command that will run what you want to run within your container: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#cmd.  To do what you want you can do a `docker container exec -it containerid bash` after your container is running.

Comment: This is working but looking for the containerid and so on isn‘t that efficient. I‘m looking for a way where I only have to run my docker(-compose)

Comment: If you are doing a “docker-compose up” I don’t believe you can automatically bash into a service.  You can do that if you do a “docker container run” by including “-it” options.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with one Dockerfile and docker run ... like above maybe by background the wildfly output so it isn‘t blocking the further actions? E.g the & at the end of a command isn‘t working

Comment: You may be able to do it by creating a script so that wildfly will run in the background and running that in your CMD, but I'm almost certain that isn't a good practice.

Comment: Usually if you need to do something in your container after it's running you would "docker container exec" into it.